# Find Orphan Accounts in Salesforce

Tags: apex, soql, account, childrecords

I have refreshed a developer sandbox from production salesforce Org and used a third party tool to load the sample data from production Org into the developer org. The refreshed developer sandbox has good amount of sample data, but it needs a data cleanup. I need to delete orphan accounts (I consider any account without contact, opportunity, assets and cases as an Orphan account). Is there an easier way to get this info? Once this cleanup is done, I need to delete accounts with just one children (Account with only contacts, Accounts with Only Opportunities, Accounts with Only Assets, and Accounts with Only Cases). Currently I am following the below approach.

```
List of Accounts without Contacts and Opportunities.
SELECT Id from Account WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId from Contact) and Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId from Opportunity)

List of Accounts without Contacts, Opportunities, Assets, and Cases.
SELECT Id from Account WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId from Asset) and Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId from Case) and Id IN [List of Account Ids from first query]
```

The above solution works, but I am looking for a better solution, especially when I need to delete Accounts with only one children record types (Contact, Opportunities, Assets, Cases etc)

In the worst case scenario, I can code this in Apex and I can re-use it in the future whenever needed.

Is there any other alternative to achieve this?